# Best way to manage multiple Localization on Xcode

Tags: xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have transformed all string in my project to NSLocalizedString.

Now, what are the best way to manage multiple language. (I see that Xcode doesn't have a "grid view", where I can be sure all string was translated to each language.

So, how to easily move NSLocalizedString to each Localizable.strings (english, french, etc).  Doing this manually seems long and not easy to keep clean.

Comment: I have also found a plug-in.  https://github.com/Loongwoo/StringManage

It doesn't do what I want, but it can show a grid of Localized.string versus how many time they are used.  (but not able to add directly to the Localized.string).  I still find the processus not user friendly.  I'm surprised no user friendly tool for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in Terminal on root folder of your project.

```
find ./ -name "*.m" -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -o en.lproj
```

This will create Localizable.strings file in folder en.lproj.